Power BI Matrix Visualization - Hide Columns with no Data Automatically
I am creating a Matrix in Power BI to display total production & area (not-specific to customers), Supplies (customer specific). To do this I created a customer called area and production. This allows me to show the data in the correct fields. However, these fields are repeated for each customer even if empty. I have ensured that the show items with no data is not checked.
I have my products in the Rows. The customers in Columns and Production, Area, Supply and %conversion in the values.
I would like to know how to automatically hide the columns for production and area when the customer is not production and area (Column labeled P %)
I manaully tried to hide these columns (using single character headers) then reducing the space, however this doesnt work when I have new customers.

